# R programming help: deals with reordering

Tags: r

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGagy.png)

I need help with number 2 on this assignment I named the data set Bike just so you know. I don't really need help creating the tables just the whole reordering part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at [Re-ordering factor levels in data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413756/re-ordering-factor-levels-in-data-frame) and [Reorder levels of a factor without changing order of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375587/reorder-levels-of-a-factor-without-changing-order-of-values)

Comment: They want me to order things from the different variables of the data frame though ... like order the different graduation statuses in the order on the assignment. And the yes and no.  That's what confuses me... I know how to do it to the entire data frame

Comment: Maybe this gets at your question better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413756/re-ordering-factor-levels-in-data-frame

Comment: You're a life saver! Thank you so much!!