# Manually order ggplot2 legend when overlaying multiple plots of multiple data.frames

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am making CDF plots using this line of code:

```
library(ggplot2)
ExpDF <- data.frame(x=c('gene1','gene2','gene3','gene4'),"FC"=c(1,2,3,4))
ts_miR_15 <- data.frame(x=c('gene1','gene3','gene4'),"FC"=c(1,3,4))
ahc_miR_15_3UTR <- data.frame(x=c('gene1','gene4','gene12'),"FC"=c(1,4,12))

g <- ggplot(data = NULL)
g + geom_step(aes(x=ExpDF$FC, color="All_genes"),stat="ecdf") +
    geom_step(aes(x= ts_miR_15$FC, color="Targetscan_miR-15/16"), stat="ecdf") + 
    geom_step(aes(x= ahc_miR_15_3UTR$FC, color="3UTR_miR-15/16_seed"), stat="ecdf") +
    scale_colour_manual("Subsets", values = c("All_genes"='black',
                        "Targetscan_miR-15/16"='orange',
                        "3UTR_miR-15/16_seed"='red'))
```

...(etc. for each additional data.frame

I would like to be able to reorder the labels for the legend such that "All_genes" is on top (and preferably have it in any oder I want). I would prefer to keep the data.frames separate because they have different numbers of genes (which mark the rows) in them and some of them are subsets of the other.

Comment: You need to reorder them as.factors.

Comment: In case you want to know how to reorder not only in reverse but as desired: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413756/re-ordering-factor-levels-in-data-frame

Comment: Thank you for the comments, I have seen those other posts but they refer to plotting a single data.frame and not multiple where I want to use my own labels and colors in a specific order for each data.frame. @Masoud, could you explain how I would apply as.factors in this case to reorder the labels?

Comment: @JohnGagnon Yes. If you provide a reproducible example. Please read [How to make a great reproducible example in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: That's not reproducible code. `etc.`? you can make a minimal example by making only two or three data frames and not completed records of them. don't use `...` or `etc.`.

Comment: @Masoud Sorry, I was trying to make it clear that there was a much larger data set and that the number of rows in each data.frame is different. I have tried to make the code reproducible. Thanks!