# How to change hcaes group order using R?

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I´m doing a column graph using Highcharts and I´m trying to change the order of group appearance.

This is my data.table:

[image]

and this is my code and graph:

```
      hchart(data,type = "column", hcaes(x = DATA , y = VALUE, group = TIPO )) %>%
        hc_xAxis(title = NULL) %>%
        hc_yAxis(title = "undefined") %>%
        hc_exporting(enabled = TRUE) %>%
        hc_colors(c("#336600","#990000","#006666"))
```

[image]

I want to present for each year, first IN, then OUT and finally NET. (basically need to change Net with Out)

Comment: Have you tried to change upstream the `TIPO` levels order before launching your `hchart` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413756/re-ordering-factor-levels-in-data-frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following *Yacine Hajji* comment.

Data:

```
data <- structure(list(Anos = c("2021", "2022", "2021", "2022", "2021", "2022"), 
                       Value = c(12539517L, 5418597L, 3827159L, 4457460L, 8712360L, 961152L),
                       Tipo = c("IN", "IN", "OUT", "OUT", "NET", "NET")), 
                  row.names = c(NA, -6L),
                  class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Changing upstream the `Tipo` levels:

```
data$Tipo <- factor(data$Tipo, levels = c("IN", "OUT", "NET"))
```

Plot:

```
hchart(data,type = "column", hcaes(x = Anos , y = Value, group = Tipo )) %>%
  hc_xAxis(title = NULL) %>%
  hc_yAxis(title = "undefined") %>%
  hc_exporting(enabled = TRUE) %>%
  hc_colors(c("#336600","#990000","#006666"))
```

[image]